# how to get the admin login page by inserting /ci-admin like /wp-admin in wordpress

Tags: codeigniter, url, admin

I am wondering if that is possible to view the admin login page just by typing /CI_ADMIN after the domain name just like we do in wordpress.

```
http://www.abc.com/wp-admin
```

and I want to do

```
http://www.abc.com/ci-admin
```

for my codeigniter website. is that possible ? the url thing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do this with routes just define route in you routes.php file

```
$route['ci-admin'] = 'ci_admin/login';
```

for more how to create admin panel please read this article specially third method

[CI Admin panel](http://philsturgeon.co.uk/blog/2009/07/Create-an-Admin-panel-with-CodeIgniter)